# Неправильно работает код для проверки существования файлов в папке

Tags: java, файлы

Есть форма в которой выбирается путь к каталогу и в этом каталоге должна следовать проверка. Есть ли там файлы или нет. Т.е. пустой каталог или нет. 
Вот код который я написал, только он не работает. Условие не выполняется. Выдает просто один и тот же результат при разных моих действиях. Выбираю каталог с файлами, все ОК, выбираю без файлов, тоже все ОК.

Что здесь не так?

```
public void btn_ShoocePath(ActionEvent event) {

    final DirectoryChooser directoryChooser = new DirectoryChooser();
    Stage stage = (Stage) Sima.getScene().getWindow();
    File dir = directoryChooser.showDialog(stage);

    txtFieldPath.setText(dir.getAbsolutePath());
}


public void btn_FindVirus(ActionEvent event) {

    File file = new File(txtFieldPath.getText());
    if (txtFieldPath.getText().equals("Выберите папку для поиска...")) {
        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Выберите каталог!!!");
    } else if (file.exists()) {
        txtFieldPath.setText("Отлично, файлы в каталоге есть!");
        // Код программы поиска вируса
    } else {
        txtFieldPath.setText("В каталоге файлов НЕТ!");
    }

}
```

Comment: Ну так вы указываете каталог и спрашиваете существует ли он? Он, конечно, существует. Нужно же проверять не пуст ли он

Comment: Спасибо. Но как проверить есть ли файлы (при условии что в папке есть другие папки )? Да и собственно не подскажите, как проверить папку, пуста ли она ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    File file = new File("C:/someDir");
    checkIsEmpty(file);
}
private static void checkIsEmpty(File file) {
    if(file.isDirectory()){
        if(file.list().length>0){
            System.out.println(file + " - директория не пустая");
            for (String path : file.list()) {
                File f = new File(file.getPath() + "/" + path);
                if (f.isFile()){
                    System.out.println(f + " - этой файл");
                } else {
                    checkIsEmpty(f);
                }
            }
        }else {
            System.out.println(file + " - директория пустая");
        }
    }
}
```

Так же можно использовать [NIO Walking the File Tree](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/io/walk.html)

```
boolean exists = file.exists();           // Проверяет существует ли путь.
boolean isDirectory = file.isDirectory(); // Проверяет директория ли это.
boolean isFile = file.isFile();           // Проверяет файл ли это.
```

`java.io.File` - может указывать как на директорию так и на файл.

Comment: @ToysUnderway, Для таких целей, лучше воспользоваться `SimpleFileVisitor`